# encapsulate gmap's InfoWindow into a function isn't going to work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

1. if i create gmap's marker and infowindow in the same function without calling other function. i works well.
2. BUT now, if i want to encapsulate some operations in a function createMarkerInfoWin(), how can i do...

i tried like this:

1) call function onLoad() when page loading.

```
function onLoad(){
    loadmap();
    var marker =   createMarkerInfoWin(); //i want to encapsulate some operations in it
    marker.setMap(map);  
    ...

}
```

2)

```
function createMarkerInfoWin(){
    var marker = new marker();
    var info = new infoWindow();
    var html = "<div>....</div>";  //infowindow's content

    Event.addlistener(marker,'click', function(){
       info.open(html,marker);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

it isn't going to work. marker is showed on the map, but infowindow not when click the marker.

So i guess: the object info's mem is going to be recycled when function return.

hi, everybody, is there a better way to encapsulate the create operation in a function?
i just don't want to put all the code in the function onLoad().

tks...